# Display Blog as WebPart in Sharepoint 2010

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, rss, web-parts

I have a blog in a Sharepoint 2010 site (hosted by a 3rd party), and I need to display snippets (title) of last 5 blog posts in the home page of my SharePoint site as a web part.

I have tried to pull the RSS XML of the blog and transform it with XSL, but for that to work the site needs to have anonymous access, which unfortunatelty is out of my hand, that is I cannot do that. I cannot upload a custom web part as well. I can create a Silverlight app, and host in the Silverlight web part, but for that I need to have cross-script enabaled in the Sharepoint, which is again cannot be done as the Sharepoint site is hosted by a 3rd party.

Can anyone please help me and let me know if there is any way, I can do that.

Thanks.

Comment: It's unclear whether you're saying your SharePoint site needs anonymous access or the blog needs anonymous access in order to get the RSS feed.

Comment: No, what I wanted is a way to acheive what I want, that is display top 5 post of a SP blog in a SP home page as a web part.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have found three ways to displaying this:

1) I user use a Content Query Webpart to pull out the data from a Sharepoint Blog and make an setting to show only the top 5 items.

2) I could use XML Viewer webpart to pull the RSS feed of the blog and use a XSL Transformation to display the top 5 items.

3) I could use a Silverlight Webpart to host a Silverlight application which will read the RSS and display the data likewise.

Answer (score 0):

So the limitation here is that you can't get anonymous access to the site - presumably you're using Basic or Forms authentication?

I think the way around then is either create your own RSS style web that can do authenticated access to the RSS XML feed using a service account - this then requires nothing to be installed or changed on the 'source' server.

Comment: I am not sure, I understand you totally. What i basically want is to show the top 5 items of a SP blog in my SP home page as a web part. I have both the approach of using XMLWebPart to RSS and using Silverlight to read it. Even if I try to acess it from a external site (asp.net, console app etc) it given "Unauthorized Access" error.

Comment: You're going to have to clarify your question - at least two people have read it and are not sure what your asking "What I want is what I want" isn't really making it any clearer.